# In Maven, how do I make the version of my build use the version of one of its dependencies?

Tags: maven, jenkins, intellij-idea, versioning, dependency-management

I'm building a helper library for an external dependency. How can I make the version of my build take from the version of the external dependency?

```
  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
  <version>???</version>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.external.dependency</groupId>
        <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.42</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

I want my library to build as 3.0.42 as well to reflect that it's a helper for that version (and possibly some older versions) of that external dependency.

Comment: Only by externally manipulating the file setting the version (XSLT would be good for this).  Maven does not provide for anything but plain string values here.  That is by design.

Comment: Note that however you can say that you want the version of your dependency to be ${project.version} (or similar) turning the tables around.  Note that you should be using snapshots while developing making this less feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either follow @Thorbjørn's suggestion to use `${project.version}` in the dependency tag.

Alternatively, you can define a property `<revision>` in the properties section of your POM (note that the name is important, don't try another property name) and define both the `<version>` in the project and the library as `${revision}`.

The second approach requires a reasonably new Maven version (like 3.5.x or 3.6.x).